# error in codeigniter ( data not inserted in mysql database)

Tags: codeigniter

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Employee extends CI_Controller {

public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->load->model('employee_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('employee_form');
    }
    public function employee_form()
    {
    $save=array(
                'emp_name'  => $this->input->post('emp_name'),
                'emp_gender' => $this->input->post('emp_gender'),
                'emp_email'  => $this->input->post('emp_email'),
                'emp_phone'  => $this->input->post('emp_phone'),
                'emp_address'   => $this->input->post('emp_address')
               );
    $this->employee_model->saveemployee($save);
    redirect('employee/index');
    }   

}
```

This is my code above and error shown blow I am fresher in CodeIgniter I need help

This is an error

[image]

Comment: Please post your model code in question.

Comment: In codeigniter you do not need to close the controllers / models / libraries with `?>`  reason http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag

Answer (score 1):

Alway model name is start from capital letter. First fixd that. Then chek database setting

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the db library first. In

autoload.php :

```
$autoload[‘libraries’] = array(‘database’);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->load->model('employee_model');
    $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
    private $employee_model = 'employee_model';
    }
```

First set it in construct
and then, call it like this

```
$this->{employee_model}->saveemployee($save);
```